# How to add “Embedded Binaries” with xcodebuild command line instead Xcode

Tags: ios, xcodebuild

I use the script to generate two types of ipa（contains today plugin and do not include today plugin).So I cannot add Embedded Binaries with Xcode.
Does anyone know the command line how to add Embedded Binaries?

Comment: I'd like to know the answer to this too.  No doubt the answer is buried in coco pods or Carthage scripts.

Comment: Got the answer ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what your setup is, but this might help. I've done something similar by adding a 'New Run Script Phase' at the end of my target's Build Phases. Something like this:

```
rm -Rf "$TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH/YOUR.framework"
mkdir -pv "$TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH/YOUR.framework"
cp -R "SOURCE_FOLDER/YOUR.framework" "$TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH"
```

Where `SOURCE_FOLDER` and `YOUR.framework` are placeholders for names according to your needs and configuration.

`$TARGET_BUILD_DIR` and `$FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH` are both defined by Xcode for you.

You've surely solved this by now but my answer may be of use to those who stumble across this in future, perhaps combined with user-defined build settings for parameterisation.